# Didn't find class "org.apache.log4j.Logger" on path: DexPathList[

Tags: android, log4j

I have my jar files in lib folder.  I have added all needed dependencies in gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
provided files('libs/asmack-android-6-0.8.2.jar')
provided files('libs/bcprov-jdk15on-147.jar')
provided files('libs/jdom-2.0.4.jar')
provided files('libs/jetty-continuation-8.1.10.v20130312.jar')
provided files('libs/jetty-http-8.1.10.v20130312.jar')
provided files('libs/jetty-io-8.1.10.v20130312.jar')
provided files('libs/jetty-server-8.1.10.v20130312.jar')
provided files('libs/jetty-util-8.1.10.v20130312.jar')
provided files('libs/jetty-websocket-8.1.10.v20130312.jar')
provided files('libs/sc-light-jdk15on-1.47.0.2.jar')
provided files('libs/scpkix-jdk15on-1.47.0.2.jar')
provided files('libs/scprov-jdk15on-1.47.0.2.jar')
provided files('libs/servlet-api-3.0.jar')
provided files('libs/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar')
provided files('libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar')
provided files('libs/slf4j-jdk14-1.7.12.jar')
provided files('libs/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar')

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class);
```

I have a lot of `ClassNoTFound`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In your build.gradle file, try the following:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar')
    // Other dependencies.
}
```

Also, try to clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: I still not able to load it. I tried and  always have the same issue : Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.log4j.Logger" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app